# I'm having trouble sending POST request to mongodb. Is my schema and request correct?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, post

I'm trying to create a backend for displaying food recipes. A recipe can have many ingredients so I came up with a schema for them.

This is the recipe schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const RecipeSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    ingredients: [
        { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ingredients' },
    ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe', RecipeSchema);
```

And this is the ingredient schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const IngredientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ingredients', IngredientSchema);
```

I already have saved some ingredients in the mongodb database. I can get the ingredients by sending a GET request.
I'm having trouble when I try to POST the recipe with the Ingredient Id in the array. I'm trying to post with postman and it doesn't show any errors but the request is never completed it's stuck on sending request.

```
{
    "title":"Some recipe",
    "description":"Some recipe is very good",
    "ingredients":["6106c09c19f8295424ea1969","6106c1137f104247d8c2d8ef"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a CORS issue. Using cors fixed it for me. The schema works and POSTs correctly